# How do I use MVC3 editor templates for lists with add and delete with the Razor viewengine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How do I use MVC3 editor templates for lists with add and delete?

I have an object:

```
public class Policy
{
    public List<PolicyLine> PolicyLines = new List<PolicyLine>();
}

public class PolicyLine
{
    public PolicyLine(bool isPositive, string policyText)
    {
        IsPositive = isPositive;
        PolicyText = policyText;
    }

    public bool IsPositive { get; set; }

    public string PolicyText { get; set; }
}
```

I have an editorTemplate: in Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Policy.cshtml and Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\PolicyLine.cshmtml and I'm wondering how to enable users to add and delete PolicyLines from the Policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work for me:

Here is my Views/Policy/Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Policy")) {
<fieldset>
@Html.EditorForModel()
</fieldset>
}
```

Here is my Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Policy.cshtml

```
@model Policy
<br />
<label for="IsPositive">Is positive?</label>
@Html.CheckBox("IsPositive")
<input type="text" name="PolicyText" />
<input type="submit" value="Add to Policy"  title="SubmitFromReferalPolicy" />
@Html.EditorFor(a => a.PolicyLines)
```

Here is my Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PolicyLine.cshtml

```
@model PolicyLine
<br />
@this.Model.ToString()
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteLine/" + Model.Identifier.ToString())
```

Here is my Policy.cs

```
public class Policy
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public List<PolicyLine> PolicyLines = new List<PolicyLine>();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return PolicyFormatter.FormatPolicy(this);
    }
}
```

Here is my PolicyLine.cs

```
public class PolicyLine
{
    public bool IsPositive { get; set; }

    public string PolicyText { get; set; }

    public Guid Identifier { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return PolicyFormatter.FormatPolicyLine(this);
    }
}
```

Here is my add method from PolicyController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(PolicyLine submitted)
    {
        Policy saveMe = Policy.GetPolicyFromUserName(UserName);
        submitted.Identifier = Guid.NewGuid();
        saveMe.PolicyLines.Add(submitted);
        Store.Write(saveMe);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here is my delete method from PolicyController.cs

```
    public ActionResult DeleteLine(Guid identifier)
    {
        Policy saveMe = Policy.GetPolicyFromUserName(UserName);
        PolicyLine removeMe = saveMe.PolicyLines.Find(p => p.Identifier == identifier);
        saveMe.PolicyLines.Remove(removeMe);
        Store.Write(saveMe);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the DELETE, just add the following line to the PolicyLine.cshtml and add a Delete Action to your Controller to perform the delete.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Model.PolicyID })
```

The ADD is a bit trickier, you could add button to you Policy.cshtml and then call some javascript to insert some html on the fly.
OR 
You could have the button display a new page to capture the new policyline and then return to the original page with the new line added.